# Not Showing Firebase Test Native Express ads, getting only live ads, also how to make Native express ads fit the width?

Tags: android, firebase, native, ads

i have set test device sill getting live ads..

```
mAdView = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("722378CE522E161F0EFAD13A658F5161")
    .addTestDevice("048B0A7DC3863535720E0C21AC1C58FD")
    .build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and my xml code is:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/l2"
        ads:adSize="360x80"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/native_ads"
/>
```

Comment: Right now Admob NativeExpressAdView not having test ad feature, i hope admob will release test ad for native ads in future

Answer (score 12):

For getting test native express ads, use following ad unit id-

```
<string name="native_ad_test_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

For getting full width ads, use the FULL_WIDTH constant in the adSize.
For example, your code should be

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/l2"
        ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx80"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/native_ads"
/>
```

Comment: You can also read the posts from the AdMob team:
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/XsWEj7qa5NI
They suggest the same action at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

Use

> **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111**

**instead** of your **own Ad unit id**.

Answer (score 0):

As described here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-advanced

it is possible to use

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511